# Nodejs, express http request - response not unzipping

Tags: node.js, https

I am trying to write a function that creates an HTTPS request.

This is all part of an expressjs project with Typescript.

I can get the HTTPS request working and getting a response - but the response is encoded with GZIP. I am trying my best to follow the documentation. But no luck, the response stays zipped.

This is my code

```
private getData = (host, pathname): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            hostname: host,
            path: pathname,
            gzip: true,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'x-apikey': 'XXXX'}
        }
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                console.log('error!')
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
            }
            let body = '';
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                try {
                    console.log('res.headers', res.headers)
                    console.log('res.headers', body)

                    body = JSON.parse.toString();

                    resolve(body);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
            req.on('error', (e) => {
                reject(e.message);
            });
            // send the request

        });
        req.end();
    });
}
```

The console log statement shows this
[image]

So obviously the JSONparsing is failing. What am I missing?

Thanks heaps for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https.request()` does not natively support gzip compression.   So, you will have to either add support for it yourself as shown [here](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) or use an https request library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) that already supports gzip (and also already supports promises too).

```
import got from 'got';

private getData = (host, pathname): Promise<string> => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'x-apikey': 'XXXX'}
    }
    return got(`https://${host}${pathname}`, options).json();
}
```

---

FYI, it's not clear in your question what type of response you are expecting.  You attempt to use:

```
body = JSON.parse.toString();
```

which doesn't make any sense because `JSON.parse.toString()` is trying to get string version of the `JSON.parse` function without actually even calling that function - very odd.  Perhaps you meant `JSON.parse(body)`?  But, your typescript makes it look like you're expecting a promise that resolves to a string so that wouldn't usually be the result of JSON parsing.

If you are expecting a gzipped JSON response, then you would use the:

```
return got(`https://${host}${pathname}`, options).json();
```

I show above.  If you are expecting just a string, not JSON, then you would change that line to:

```
return got(`https://${host}${pathname}`, options).text();
```

Comment: thanks heaps for help, will try it now!

Comment: The above solution works, but I opted to write my own solution inn the end. The answer helped me to understand the problem.